# How to align a list in an __str__ output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

When I add alignment to the code below

```
class MyClass():

    def __init__(self, a = None, b = [], c = None):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def __str__(self):
        return "a: {}, b: {}, c:{}".format(
            self.a, self.b, self.c)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = MyClass(1, [1,2], 2)
    print(obj)
```

in particular, to its list argument, like

```
class MyClass():

    def __init__(self, a = None, b = [], c = None):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def __str__(self):
        return "a: {:<3}, b: {:<3}, c:{:<3}".format(
            self.a, self.b, self.c)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = MyClass(1, [1,2], 2)
    print(obj)
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to list.__format__
```

What is the right way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Force the string representation of the list with a [conversion flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
def __str__(self):
    return "a: {:<3}, b: {!s:<3}, c:{:<3}".format(
        self.a, self.b, self.c)
```

The reason this happens is that `list.__format__` doesn't support alignment in the format string mini-language. The docs for [format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) describe a bit more about how this conversion feature works.

> The *conversion* field causes a type coercion before formatting. Normally, the job of formatting a value is done by the `__format__()` method of the value itself. However, in some cases it is desirable to force a type to be formatted as a string, overriding its own definition of formatting. By converting the value to a string before calling `__format__()`, the normal formatting logic is bypassed.

The same thing can be used with f-strings, with a syntax like this:

```
>>> f"{[1, 2]!s:>10}"
'    [1, 2]'
```

Comment: Thanks, but the result has no alignment for `self.b`, just like one doesn't apply that `s:<3` at all.

Comment: That's because [1, 2] is width 5, it's already wider than 3.  Use with `{!s:<10}` instead and you'll see that it is actually working.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like alignment is not supported for `list` objects. Try changing your code to:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "a: {:<3}, b: {:<3}, c:{:<3}".format(
        self.a, str(self.b), self.c)
```