# Quote string value in F-string in Python

Tags: python, string-formatting

I'm trying to quote one of the values I send to an f-string in Python:

```
f'This is the value I want quoted: \'{value}\''
```

This works, but I wonder if there's a formatting option that does this for me, similar to how `%q` works in Go. Basically, I'm looking for something like this:

```
f'This is the value I want quoted: {value:q}'
>>> This is the value I want quoted: 'value'
```

I would also be okay with double-quotes. Is this possible?

Comment: Just... use the other quotes? `f"This is the value I want quoted: '{value}'"`?

Comment: That feature doesn't exist that I am aware of.

Comment: `{value!r}` (`repr()` of the value) sort of does that, although you don't get to choose the type of quotes used.

Comment: When reading the code, I’d actually want to clearly see the quotes embedded and escaped instead of having to look up an obscure flag that automagically does it for me, but that’s just my personal preference.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar The problem with that is it's pretty tricky to figure out how to escape them correctly. Have a think about how you'd escape `value = """a'b"c"""`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans For some backstory here, I'm using this to quote string values in error messages. I'd rather have a standardized output for these which seems unlikely if I and others have to manually escape quotes.

Comment: In python 3.12 this is now easily possible: https://docs.python.org/3.12/whatsnew/3.12.html#pep-701-syntactic-formalization-of-f-strings

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [explicit conversion flag](https://peps.python.org/pep-3101/#explicit-conversion-flag) `!r`:

```
>>> value = 'foo'
>>> f'This is the value I want quoted: {value!r}'
"This is the value I want quoted: 'foo'"
```

The `r` stands for [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr); the result of `f'{value!r}'` should be equivalent to using `f'{repr(value)}'`. Conversion flags are a feature carried over from [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), which predates f-strings.

For some reason undocumented in PEP 3101, but mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), there's also an `!a` flag which converts with [`ascii`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ascii):

```
>>> f'quote {""!a}'
"quote '\\U0001f525'"
```

And there's an `!s` for [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str), which seems useless... unless you know that objects can override their formatter to do something different than [`object.__format__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__format__) does. It provides a way to [opt-out of those shenanigans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69533670/674039) and use `__str__` anyway.

```
>>> class What:
...     def __format__(self, spec):
...         if spec == "fancy":
...             return ""
...         return "potato"
...     def __str__(self):
...         return "spam"
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return "<wacky object at 0xcafef00d>"
... 
>>> obj = What()
>>> f'{obj}'
'potato'
>>> f'{obj:fancy}'
''
>>> f'{obj!s}'
'spam'
>>> f'{obj!r}'
'<wacky object at 0xcafef00d>'
```

One example of where that `!s` might be useful in practice is with alignment/padding of types that don't otherwise support it:

```
>>> f"{[1,2]:.>10}"
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to list.__format__
>>> f"{[1,2]!s:.>10}"
'....[1, 2]'
```

Or types which "support" it, but not how you may have intended:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> f"{date.today():_^14}"
'_^14'
>>> f"{date.today()!s:_^14}"
'__2024-03-25__'
```

Comment: I upvoted but probably worth pointing out that this is the same as `repr` on a string

Comment: The reason `!a` exists is to offer access to `__ascii__`, which in turn exists to help with backward-compatibility issues and migrating old code written for 2.x (arguably, also to facilitate working with older networking protocols that assume bytes can be treated as ASCII text naively).

Comment: It also helps to tell between `repr('a\u0304')` -> `"'ā'"` and `ascii('a\u0304')` -> `"'a\\u0304'"`. `repr()` isn't 100% ambiguous, but is more readable.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel As far as I know there has never been an `__ascii__` method in Python.  This conversion flag calls [`ascii`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ascii), as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @wim my mistake; I was thinking of `__bytes__`, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Also another way could be just string formatting as for example:

```
string ="Hello, this is a '%s', '%d' is a decimal, '%f' is a float"%("string", 3, 5.5)
print(string)
```

This would return:

```
Hello, this is a 'string', '3' is a decimal, '5.500000' is a float
```